# I want to edit the apache .htaccess file so that our admin URL's require the use of an edit- prefix. Will this code work?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Am somewhat new to editing the .htaccess file on an Apache web server.

I want to limit our admin/content editing URL's to the prefix edit-.

For example, our public web site might be joeswidgets.com and I want our admin/content editing url to be edit-joeswidgets.com.

From reading, I get the sense that this should work but I wanted to run it by the community first so I don't inadvertently lock everyone out of our own server.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^edit-(.+)$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^edit-(.+)$ [NC]
```

Will this work?

Thanks

Comment: So you bought a whole new domain "edit-joeswidgets.com" just for editing the website?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized. The only sensible answers are "yes" or "no" and that has no lasting value.

Comment: So you bought a whole new domain "edit-joeswidgets.com" just for editing the website?

No, it's actually a longer domain edit-joeswidgets.joeswidgets.com.

Why don't [you] just try?

That's what I was thinking, but again I'm afraid of accidentally locking out everyone from the server since I'm a front-end developer and this type of thing is completely new to me.

Answer (score 0):

> Will this work?

Yeah, that's generally what you want to do. Just keep in mind that `RewriteCond`'s *only apply to the immediately following `RewriteRule`. So if you have a bunch of rules for the main site and/or admin site, the conditions need to be repeated for each rule.